# Rails unable to update my avg columns after create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to update my column  after enter data in to database but I am getting an following error.

```
models/company_rating.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC ...ttributes :avg_satisfaction, => company_rating.collect(&:sat... ... ^ /home/seshendra/Desktop/webapp/app/models/company_rating.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
```

This what I am trying to update in my model of company_ratings

```
after_create :update_avgratings
  def update_avgratings
    rating_size = company_rating.collect(&:satisfaction).count
    update_attributes :avg_satisfaction, => company_rating.collect(&:satisfaction).sum.to_f/rating_size
   end
  end
```

More Details is I have a table with the following columns and I am trying to update it.

```
s.no  user_id company-id   r1     r2  r3     r4   avg of r1   avg of r2  avg ofr3 avg r4
1          1      1         2      3   4     5     3            4          5.6     6.6
2          2      1                4   6     7
3          1      2         4      6   7     9     4              6        7       9
4          3      1         4      5   7     8
```

So I would like to update my table as follows how can I do it. Can any one tell me after create the variable it need to be updated. to find the Avg of r1,r2,r3,r4 I am using the following formula `Sum of r1/total.no.of r1`
So can anyone tell how udate it in my model controller of ratings

So as per suggestion I have update my company model and ratings model as follows

my company model

```
def update_attribscore
    company_rating = CompanyRating.where(:company_id =>@current_user.company.id)
     rating_size=company_rating.collect(&:satisfaction).count
     update_attributes(:attrib_satisfaction => company_rating.collect(&:satisfaction).sum.to_f/rating_size)


  end
```

my ratings model

```
after_create :update_post_update_attribscore
    def update_post_update_attribscore
   self.company.update_attribscore
  end
```

But I dont know how to update the attribute score according to companyid 
And if any user 
Can anyone tell me what is my problem and how to solve this.

Comment: These averages appear to be an attribute of the Company, not the CompanyRating, so you should definitely be storing this as an attribute of the Company. To store this in the CompanyRating looks like a serious data modelling error. You could more simply and robustly store the number of ratings and total rating sum at the company level, which would give more data with little loss of performance.

Comment: Hi thank your suggestion I followed but I dont know how to update the my attrib score according to company id when company is is one 1. So can please guide me how to do that. Here I have updated my model method

Comment: The provided information is insufficient and fatal errors are seemingly endemic.

Comment: ok what information you need let know I can provide you those information.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the only issue, but one issue is that you have a comma and a hashrocket after :avg_satisfaction. You also have an extra end in the code sample, I'm not sure if that is just from a poor copy-paste or not, but the error is saying unexpected end (which would occur if you had an extra end). Remove the comma like so:

```
after_create :update_avgratings

def update_avgratings
  rating_size = collect(&:satisfaction).count
  update_attributes(:avg_satisfaction => collect(&:satisfaction).sum.to_f/rating_size)
end
```

Comment: I am getting  following error undefined method `collect' for #<CompanyRating:0x007f1c8c887c28>

Answer (score 1):

You have an extraneous comma that's causing the syntax error. Try the following:

```
update_attributes(:avg_satisfaction => company_rating.collect(&:satisfaction).sum.to_f/rating_size)
```

The `update_attribute` class method expects key-value pairs as arguments. In Ruby, key-value pairs are denoted in one of two ways:

1. Hash rocket: `a => b`
2. Colon: `a: b`

Note that commas are used for *delimiting* key-value pairs – they can't be invoked otherwise, as you've done in your code.

**UPDATE**:

Based on the comments to this question, the following should provide a measure of `avg_satisfaction`:

```
company_rating.collect(&:satisfaction).inject(:+) / company_rating.collect(&:satisfaction).count
```

**EXPLANATION**:

Broken into parts:

*Part I*: `company_rating.collect(&:satisfaction).inject(:+)`

`company_rating.collect(&:satisfaction)` returns an array of values – presumably integers. `inject(:+)` utilizes the core Ruby [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) method to summate values of the collection/array.

*Part II*: `company_rating.collect(&:satisfaction).count`

Again, `company_rating.collect(&:satisfaction)` returns an array of values. The [`count`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-count) method simply returns the summation of the number of members of the array.

Comment: My answer already says this, I'm not sure why post this answer afterwards?

Comment: Perhaps it's because I was writing this answer as you were posting yours. It wasn't done deliberately.

Comment: thank you for both your answers it works but I am getting an error that undefined method company_ratings. Actually I am updating the same table column so How to do that.

Comment: @zeantsoi, nice edit though - yours now provides more details on the problem.

Comment: @user3144005 if the model you are calling this on is company_ratings, you do not need to access it via company_ratings in an instance method, you can simply not use anything or use self.

Comment: I want to do the sum and count operation where I am getting an error Sum is undefined update_attributes(:avg_satisfaction => self.SUM(:satisfaction)/COUNT(:satisfaction))

Comment: actually I wanted make sum of satisfaction parameter by its count So How can I do it

Comment: @user3144005, have a look at my update and explanation.

Comment: You need to post more of your model code. How much experience with Rails do you have? You might benefit from some remedial lessons on ActiveRecord.

Comment: @user3144005, unless you can provide some more relevant insight, I'll be compelled to downvote your question and vote to close it.

Comment: @zeantsoi I have added the more information please help me how to do it. I am a newbie in rails.

Comment: Based on the information provided, this question is not answerable, IMO. I would recommend that you close the question.